# Datatable print blank table issue

Tags: jquery, datatable, datatables

I'm using data-table in my website only problem is when I click on print button it display blank table with border see attached file : https://i.stack.imgur.com/CsQ5F.png. When I refresh my page it shows data. Here is my code please check :

```
$('#data-table').DataTable({
    dom: 'Bfrtip',
    destroy: true,
    searching: false,
    info: false,
    buttons: [{
        text: 'Email',
        className: 'btn-warning btn_send_email',
        title: $('#dll_suser option:selected').text()
    },
    {
        extend: 'excel',
        className: 'btn-success',
        title: $('#dll_suser option:selected').text()
    },
    {
        extend: 'pdf',
        className: 'btn-danger',
        title: $('#dll_suser option:selected').text()
    },
    {
        extend: 'csv',
        className: 'btn-success',
        title: $('#dll_suser option:selected').text()
    },
    {
        extend: 'print',
        className: 'btn-info print_btn',
        text: 'Print',
        autoPrint: true,
        exportOptions: {
            columns: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
        },
        customize: function(win) {
            $(win.document.body).find('table').addClass('display').css({
                'font-size': '12px'
            });
            $(win.document.body).find('th,td').each(function(index) {
                $(this).css({
                    'text-align': 'center',
                    'padding': '5px 10px'
                });
            });
            $(win.document.body).find('h1').css({
                'text-align': 'center',
                'font-size': '16px',
                "float": 'left',
                'width': '100%'
            });
            $(win.document.body).find('h1').text('Monthly Sling Check : ' + org_name);
            $(win.document.body).find('h1').after('<div style="text-align:center; width:100%;float:left;"><div style="float:left;"> DOB : ' + $('#dll_suser option:selected').attr('dob') + '</div><div style="float:right;"> Room No. : ' + $('#dll_suser option:selected').attr('room_no') + '</div></div>');
            $(win.document.body).find('h1').after('<div style=" width:100%; text-align:center;"><div style="float:left;">Service User(SU) : ' + $('#dll_suser option:selected').text() + '</div><div style="float:right">Date : ' + start_date + ' TO ' + end_date + '</div></div>');
            $(win.document.body).css('height', 'auto');
        }
    }],
    fixedHeader: {
        header: !0,
        headerOffset: $("#header").height()
    },
    responsive: true
});
```

Comment: Have you used print media css..?

Comment: Please add this line before closing head tag `@media print
   {
      body {color:black !important;}
   }`

Comment: No I've not used print media, datatable was printing blank page at last after printing all the pages.  I put this code  : body,html{height:100%}